# Angular 2 Release 6 how to add esri ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.24

Tags: angular, esri

I'm currently converting a Angular 1 release X website to Angular 2 Release 5 website.  In the original app ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.24 was used and I'm going to use that on the new project.  In the site's index.html I've got:

**EDIT**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.24/esri/css/esri.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.24compact"></script>

<script>
    require(["esri/config", "esri/tasks/GeometryService", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function(esriConfig, GeometryService) {
        esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/api/esriproxy/";
        esriConfig.defaults.geometryService = new GeometryService("https:someurl.com");
    });
</script>
```

Not really sure what to do to add esri to the project to get the map to show.  Any pointers to good examples would be appreciated as the documentation addresses really old versions of angular.
I've already found how to add the esri loader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use Arcgis JS API with the latest version of Angular (v6 for now), the best way to go is to use the "esri-loader" npm package ([Documentation here](https://github.com/Esri/esri-loader)) as you mentionned and then use it in custom services.

With the esri-loader you just need to add the link tag in index.html: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.24/esri/css/esri.css">` and then use esri-loader to load the `js-api`.

Here is a service example with Angular 6 + Arcgis JS API v4.7, I basically use a service to use the esri-loader as necessary (you can do the same way with v3.24):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { loadModules, loadScript } from 'esri-loader';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ArcgisApiService {
  loaded$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor() {
    this.loaded$.subscribe(loaded => {
      if (!loaded) {
        loadScript({
          // use a specific version of the JSAPI
          url: 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.7/'
        })
          .then(() => {
            this.loaded$.next(true)
          }).catch(err => this.loaded$.next(true))
      }
    });
  }

  constructMap(opts: { basemap: any; elevation: boolean }): Promise<any[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      loadModules(['esri/Map']).then(([Map]) => {
        const map = new Map({
          basemap: opts.basemap
        });
        if (opts.elevation) {
          map.ground = 'world-elevation';
        }
        resolve(map);
      });
    });
  }

  constructSceneView(opts: {
    center: number[];
    zoom: number;
    container: string;
    map: any;
    padding?: any;
  }): Promise<any[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      loadModules(['esri/views/SceneView'])
        .then(([SceneView]) => {
          const view = new SceneView({
            center: opts.center,
            zoom: opts.zoom,
            map: opts.map,
            container: opts.container,
            padding: opts.padding ? opts.padding : {}
          });
          view.when(() => {
            resolve(view);
          });
        });
    });
  }
}
```

You can then build reusable components using your custom services or directly use the services in your component class.

Here is a full example: [Angular 6 + Arcgis API v4.7 (Stackblitz)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-arcgis-api).

**----- EDIT -------**

Here is a full example with Arcgis API v3.24 + Angular 6 :
[Angular 6 + Arcgis API 3.24 (Stackblitz)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-arcgis-api-3)

**-----------------------**

You have this way a total control on the API and it opens you pretty cool possibilities!

Comment: i had to make a change on the script to use "https://js.arcgis.com/3.24compact" , also I need to be able to set the extent and extent layer.  Is that possible on your stackblitz?

Comment: Oh great! It was an example to show you how to go. You can, with this basis, build everything you want, like my reusable MapComponent in my example.

Comment: how do I handle the the require in the script section of the index.html though?

Comment: As I already said use the `esri-loader` to do that and don't put this logic in the `index.html` file. Launch this in you `app.component.ts`file: 

`import {loadModules} from 'esri-loader';`

`constructor() { 
   loadModules(["esri/config", "esri/tasks/GeometryService", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function(esriConfig, GeometryService) {
        esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/api/esriproxy/";
        esriConfig.defaults.geometryService = new GeometryService("https:someurl.com");
    })
};`